# I get an error which I can't understand in java while getting a user input

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class KK {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    
        Scanner myObj = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter username");

        String userName = myObj.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Username is: " + userName);

    }

}
```

This is the error I get

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 

    at ekdum.KK.main(KK.java:4)
```

Comment: I tried to compile your code and it compiles fine. This smells of an IDE that didn't recompile your code, so rebuild manually and retry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error normally occurs, if you use eclipse and your source file has errors. If there are any errors the java compiler from eclipse emits code, that throws an error.
Try to clean and rebuild

Answer (score -1):

It worked , I tried it again by creating a new class and it worked, Thanks